# Not working properly flash messages in angular 5

Tags: angular

I get this error when I import angular flash messages. I followed this link to install it. https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-flash-message. But I get this [image: Error]. I already setup the all components according to the given guide.

This is my app.componenet.html

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<div class="container">


  <flash-messages></flash-messages>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>




</div>
```

This is my register.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService} from '../../service/auth.service';
import {FlashMessage} from 'angular-flash-message';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  name:String;
  username:String;
  email:String;
  password:String;

  constructor(
    private authService:AuthService,
    private flashMessage: FlashMessage
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  registerData(){

    const user = {
      name:this.name,
      username:this.username,
      email:this.email,
      password:this.password
    };

    this.authService.registerUser(user).subscribe(res=>{


      if(res.state) {
       // this.flashMessage.show("You're registered", {cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 3000});
       this.flashMessage.success('Success registered');
       // this.router.navigate(['/login']);

      }else {
       // this.flashMessage.show("something went wrong", {cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout: 3000});
       this.flashMessage.success('something went wrong');
       // this.router.navigate(['/register']);
      }

    });
  }

}
```

This is myapp.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule,Routes } from '@angular/router';
import {FlashMessageModule} from 'angular-flash-message';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './components/register/register.component';

import { AuthService } from './service/auth.service';


const applicationRoutes:Routes = [

  {path:'login',component:LoginComponent},
  {path:'register',component:RegisterComponent},
  //{path:'profile',component:ProfileComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard]},


];


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(applicationRoutes),
    FlashMessageModule
  ],
  providers: [AuthService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I already tried by changing, import {FlashMessageModule} from 'angular-flash-message'; to import {FlashMessageModule} from 'angular2-flash-message'; . But it doesn't work as well.

I can't figure out why this error come out as I'm already set up correctly. Please any one help me.

Comment: Please check this working code snippet:
https://therichpost.com/angular-6-flash-messages

Comment: I got this error too, did any one resolve this before ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if npm actually installed it. sometimes it doesn't go quite alright you know.

Answer (score 0):

In your app.module.ts file try changing import from

```
imports: [
//
FlashMessagesModule,
//
]
```

to

```
imports: [
//
FlashMessagesModule.forRoot(),
//
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work well because that version of flash messages is deprecated. I've been in the same situation but this worked for me

```
npm install angular2-flash-messages --save
```

after that, in your app.module.ts

```
import {FlashMessagesModule } from 'angular2-flash-messages';
```

then in your imports

```
imports: [
    ...
    FlashMessagesModule.forRoot()
  ],
```

Your app.component.ts should look like this

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<div class="container">
  <flash-messages></flash-messages>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

then in your register

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService} from '../../service/auth.service';
import { FlashMessagesService } from 'angular2-flash-messages';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  name:String;
  username:String;
  email:String;
  password:String;

  constructor(
    private authService:AuthService,
    private _flashMessagesService: FlashMessagesService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  registerData(){

    const user = {
      name:this.name,
      username:this.username,
      email:this.email,
      password:this.password
    };

    this.authService.registerUser(user).subscribe(res=>{
```